# sampler2D in compute shaders, compilation errors

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader, opengl-4

I'm trying to port a Windows program to GNU/Linux, but a compute shader doesn't compile.

I have a few knowledge of GLSL. So I wonder if there are workarounds to get the shader working.

I have written a minimal example that shows the compilation errors.

Here is the compute shader:

```c
#version 430 core
#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 : enable
//#extension GL_ARB_bindless_texture : enable

layout(binding = 1) uniform TextureHandles {
    uvec2 texture_handles[512];
};

vec3 SampleTexture(uint texture_index, vec2 uv) {
    uv.y = 1.f - uv.y;
    sampler2D tex_sampler = sampler2D(texture_handles[texture_index]);
    return textureLod(tex_sampler, uv, 0.0f).xyz;
}

void main() {
}
```

Here are the compilation errors:

```
0:11(2): error: image/sampler variables may only be declared as function parameters or uniform-qualified global variables
0:11(2): error: opaque variables must be declared uniform
0:11(26): error: cannot initialize tex_sampler variable opaque
0:11(26): error: cannot construct opaque type `sampler2D'
0:12(20): warning: `tex_sampler' used uninitialized
```

About the construction of opaque type sampler2D, I have read on internet that the GL_ARB_bindless_texture extension needs to be enable, but when I enable it, I have an error saying that it is unsupported in a compute shader.

Here is the minimal program, using GLEW and GLFW, that shows the error:

```cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Shader programs for core profile:
//
const char * csprog_core =
"#version 430 core\n\
#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 : enable\n\
//#extension GL_ARB_bindless_texture : enable\n\
\n\
layout(binding = 1) uniform TextureHandles {\n\
    uvec2 texture_handles[512];\n\
};\n\
\n\
vec3 SampleTexture(uint texture_index, vec2 uv) {\n\
    uv.y = 1.f - uv.y;\n\
    sampler2D tex_sampler = sampler2D(texture_handles[texture_index]);\n\
    return textureLod(tex_sampler, uv, 0.0f).xyz;\n\
}\n\
\n\
void main() {\n\
}\n\
\n";


int width, height;

void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ], char *envp[ ] ) { 
  if(!glfwInit()) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
  
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Program", NULL, NULL);
  if(!window) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  glfwSwapInterval(1);
  
  glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

  // get version info
  const GLubyte* renderer;
  const GLubyte* version;

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // start GLEW extension handler
  //
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  GLenum err = glewInit();
  if(GLEW_OK != err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    return(-1);
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));
  
  // get version info
  renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
  version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version as a string
  printf("\nRenderer: %s", renderer);
  printf("\nOpenGL version supported %s\n", version);
  fflush(stdout);
  
  // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // Shaders:
  //
  GLint params;
  GLint len;

  GLuint cscore = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(cscore, 1, &csprog_core, NULL);
  glCompileShader(cscore);
  glGetShaderiv(cscore,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&params);
  if(params == GL_FALSE) {
    GLchar log[100000];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(cscore,100000,&len,log);
    printf("\n\n%s\n\n",log);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  glfwDestroyWindow(window);
  glfwTerminate();
  
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Sampler objects are opaque data types and cannot constructed like matrices, vectors or scalar types. I would recommend to read the following articles: [Sampler (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)) (especially the section **Binding textures to samplers**), [Bindless Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture), [Interface Block (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)) and/or [Compute Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader).

Comment: An alternative and simple solution would be the use of [Array Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Erdal Küçük comment, I have implemented a texture arrays. Setting its width and height to the value of the largest texture.

I have to set some uniforms, in order to compute in the shader the values u and v for each texture in function of their width and height. But the scale factor of u and v values could be precomputed on CPU.

Here is what the compute shader looks like:

```
#version 430 core
#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 : enable

uniform sampler2DArray Textures;
uniform uint maxwidth;
uniform uint maxheight;
uniform uint texwidths[MAX_TEXTURES];
uniform uint texheights[MAX_TEXTURES];

vec3 SampleTexture(uint texture_index, vec2 uv) {
    uv.y = 1.f - uv.y;
    uv.x = uv.x * float(texwidths[texture_index]) / maxwidth;
    uv.y = uv.y * float(texheights[texture_index]) / maxheight;
    return textureLod(Textures, vec3(uv, texture_index), 0.0f).xyz;
}

void main() {
}
```

The maximum number of layers of an array, that the hardware support, can be known with the following call:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS, &value);
```

To upload the texture to the GPU, I'm using this code, setting up a texture array of the maximum width and height values found in the textures:

```
GLuint texture_array = 0;
glGenTextures(1,&texture_array);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,texture_array);
int maxwidth = 0;
int maxheight = 0;
for(auto i = 0; i < textures.size(); ++i) {
  if(maxwidth < textures[i].width) maxwidth = textures[i].width;
  if(maxheight < textures[i].height) maxheight = textures[i].height;
}
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA8, maxwidth, maxheight, textures.size());
    
std::vector<u_int32_t> clear_data(maxwidth * maxheight, 0);

for (auto i = 0; i < textures.size(); ++i) {
  auto & tex = textures[i];
      
  // Set to zero the texture at layer i:
  glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, maxwidth, maxheight, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &clear_data[0]);
      
  // copy the texture to GPU at layer i:
  glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, tex.width, tex.height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texture_data[textures[i].data_start]);
  
  texwidths_[i] = tex.width;
  texheights_[i] = tex.height;
}
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, NULL);
```

Before to launch the shader computation, I just have to bind the texture array, and set the uniforms values about the width and the height of each texture.

Comment: To clear a texture image (OpenGL 4.4+), one would use [glClearTexImage](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearTexImage.xhtml) or [glClearTexSubImage](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearTexSubImage.xhtml). So, no extra data to allocate nor multiple uploads necessary.